# Move logging script into a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code (credits to https://www.alanwsmith.com/posts/20emubeubayo--capturing-python-log-output-in-a-variable). How could I move this code into a class?

```
import logging
import io

# Create the logger
logger = logging.getLogger('basic_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Setup the console handler with a StringIO object
log_capture_string = io.StringIO()
ch = logging.StreamHandler(log_capture_string)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Optionally add a formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add the console handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

# Send log messages. 
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')

# Pull the contents back into a string and close the stream
log_contents = log_capture_string.getvalue()
log_capture_string.close()

# Output as lower case to prove it worked. 
print(log_contents.lower())
```

So far, I've tried this:

```
import logging
import io


class Log:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('basic_logger')
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        # Memory handler
        self.log_capture_string = io.StringIO()
        self.ch = self.stringio_handler()
        self.logger.addHandler(self.ch)

    def stringio_handler(self):
        ch = logging.StreamHandler(self.log_capture_string)
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        return ch


loggerClass = Log()
logger = loggerClass.logger

# Send log messages.
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')

# Pull the contents back into a string and close the stream
log_contents = loggerClass.log_capture_string.getvalue()
loggerClass.log_capture_string.close()

# Output as lower case to prove it worked. 
print(log_contents.lower())
```

However, not sure if it's the correct way to do it, since I need to access the logger object and the log_capture_string StringIO separately.

Comment: What did you try so far? What is your actual problem?

Comment: @FloWil please find an update on what I did so far.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not clear what you want to achieve. Does your code work like you want it to? Any errors?